# How to Solr query condition if only one value > 0 in array field

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I have an array field in Solr. 
example: 
  "variant_qty": [
          1,
          0,
          7,
          9
        ]

I want to do that : get records if one value > 0  others must be zero.

how i can do that with solr query ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can. The straight forward solution would be to index a boolean field that determines whether the condition is true, i.e. `only_one_variant_qty:1`.

You *might* be able to hack something together using the Streaming Expressions API or a mishmash of function queries, but I weren't able to see a possible solution.